# Using @ngFor templates for radio button generation

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have the following code that I would like to use *ngFor with. The code only shows 2 radiobuttons but there are more.

```
  options: string[] = [
    'Single',
    'Married',
    'Divorced',
    'Common-law',
    'Visiting'
  ];

<input
    #single
    class = 'with-gap'
    name = 'group3'
    type = 'radio'
    id = 'single'
    value = 'Single'
    (change) = 'radioBtnChange$.next(single.value)'/>
<label for = 'single'>Single</label>

<input #married
       class = 'with-gap'
       name = 'group3'
       type = 'radio'
       id = 'married'
       value = 'Maried'
       (change) = 'radioBtnChange$.next(married.value)'/>
<label for = 'married'>Married</label>
```

Instead of writing the individual radio-buttons, how could I use @ngFor so the code could be more concise.

**EDIT1**
The syntax of the libarary is as follows:

```
  <input class="with-gap" name="group3" type="radio" id="test5" checked />
  <label for="test5">Red</label>
```

It is part of http://materializecss.com/forms.html

I have tried wrapping the input in the label but only the label gets displayed.

Thanks for any input.

**EDIT2**

```
  <label *ngFor="let option of options"  for='option' >
    <input
        #option
        type="radio"
        class = 'with-gap'
        name='group3'
        id='option'
        [value]='option'
        (change) = 'radioBtnChange$.next(option.value)'/>
  </label>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem was you are using `option` as template variable name as well as `*ngFor` current iteration value. That's why `*ngFor` is getting overriden by `#option` template of `radio` element.

You should change one of the variable name, suppose `*ngFor="let option of options"` to `*ngFor="let opt of options"`

**Markup**

```
<label *ngFor="let opt of options"  for='option' >
  <input
      #option
      type="radio"
      class = 'with-gap'
      name='group3'
      id='option'
      [value]='option'
      (change) = 'changed(opt)'/>
</label>
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/RIfGt5EWmekIrQ4pDtD6?p=preview&open=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I thought so myself when I wrapped it at first - I did have the type='radio'. However, it did not. There are no errors. Nothing was displayed. I put everthing in a div and with a label. The label displays but nothing from the *ngFor template. Bear in mind the syntax of the library I am using `<input class="with-gap" name="group3" type="radio" id="test5" checked />
    <label for="test5">Red</label>l` at [http://materializecss.com/forms.html](http://materializecss.com/forms.html)#radio

Comment: See EDIT1 above

Comment: See EDIT2 above. Sorry. Note that in the library example, the label is created after the radio-button, and NOT wrapped with the label. I suspect this is the problem, but I am uncertain how to do this.

Comment: @st_clair_clarke check updated answer, there was mistake in variable declaration naming conflicts. One variable has been overrided by second. Since they were initialized twice

Answer (score 0):

If u use at least Angular2 rc2 I believe, that should work:

```
<label *ngFor="let option of options">
  <input
    #option
    type="radio"
    class = "with-gap"
    name="group3"
    id="option"
    [value]="option"
    (change) = "radioBtnChange$.next(option.value)"/>
</label>
```

Note the " instead of ' and don't do that for='option' stuff!

Comment: Sorry, but nothing is displayed. I am using angular ~2.1.2